# Plotting lines, points, planes, triangles for technical documentation

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, visualization

I'm looking for a (free) tool to draw or plot graphics as the one linked below:
Maybe a CAD solutions could be the easiest one. But which do you recommend for this certain case? I don't want to deal with solid geometry. I only need to draw points, lines, planes, angles, ...

[image: Example 1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe Latex / TikZ ?

Comment: @MattiP.: Do make that an answer, perhaps mentioning LyX, QTikZ, and KTikZ, and the Wikipedia [Comparison of TeX editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) article? I personally still use Inkscape for illustrations, Graphviz for graphs, and LibreOffice math for the equations (incorporating SVG produced by the other tools) for my own notes, but using LaTeX and TikZ would almost certainly save me time and effort. I suspect it would do so for others, too.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I haven't thought about using a vector graphic designing tool. I gave Inkscape a try and I'm pretty happy with the result. If you want, you can convert your comment to an answer, in order that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

- [gnuplot thru Maxima](http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/Maxima/gnuplot/vector/index.html)
- [VTK thru Maxima](http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/Maxima/vtk/vector/index.html)
  *